# LaTeX introduces non-existent excess space on pdf insertion

Tags: pdf, latex, pdflatex

I try to insert a PDF file into my LaTeX document. It is properly cropped (by using the "Inkscape trick") and should easily be inserted without a problem.
LaTeX however, introduces a huge white space in the document which forces itself to create a "blank" extra page just to fit the PDF to the pages.
Just like this:

[image]

This is the code creating the problem.

```latex
\end{minipage}

... % Other code

\pagebreak
\subsection[Diagramm]{\uline{Diagramm}}
\vspace{-15pt}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=0.98\textheight]{Abbildungen/ASMD_Diagramm_v2_X.pdf}
    \caption{ASMD-Diagramm}
    \label{Fig ASMD-Diagramm}
\end{figure}

... % Other code

\pagebreak
```

Now I have another PDF which is inserted properly and exactly as expected.

I have tried the following already:

1. Recrop the PDF
2. Using the `trim` command of `\includegraphics`
3. Resizing
4. Using other file formats (all were not satisfactory)

To be honest I don't know much about LaTeX and am more of a beginner-intermediate user than someone who really know this stuff. But this bothers me and has bothered me for quite a long time already. Anyone has any idea on how to fix this or what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you a) make a compilable [mre]  and  b) provide either the document (or a suitable dummy replacement)

Comment: Just a guess without having compilable code to test: there might simply not be enough space to place a headline, a caption and and image of  0.98\textheight on a single page

Comment: I will, but may I ask where to upload the files?

Comment: There is no file upload available. You could share it via github or similar services or use a file that is already include in tex distributions (e.g. have a look at the `mwe` package)

Comment: Your comment was right. There was not enough space. Odd, because it looks like LaTeX is interpreting the PDF as a bigger file as it actually is. But it probably just sees that the "floating portions" of the document are not spaced enough. So thats maybe why it introduced such a huge space? Anyways, it helped me and solved the problem. Thank you! May you state your comment as an answer so I can mark it as answer? Otherwise I just leave it this way.

Comment: I don't think LaTeX is interpreting the PDF as a bigger file as it actually is. You only leave 2% of the text height to accommodate the section, the spacing around the image and the caption. That's not nearly enough space. Latex will notice that it can't place the block on the current page, so tries to move it to the next and gives up there. The log file should have a warning telling you that.

Comment: You could write a self-answer how you solved the problem. I'm too lazy to first having to puzzle together compilable code, before even starting to work on an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem. As discussed with `samcarter`, the space around the pdf file in the document seems to have been too small, so LaTeX couldn't accomodate for the caption, header, etc.

By trial and error, I just changed the size from:

```latex
...
\includegraphics[height=0.98\textheight]{Abbildungen/ASMD_Diagramm_v2_X.pdf}
...
```

to

```latex
...
\includegraphics[height=0.95\textheight]{Abbildungen/ASMD_Diagramm_v2_X.pdf}
...
```

and now it fits quite well on the page.